# /dev/sda removal GParted Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: partitioning, uninstall, gparted

As can be seen I reinstalled Ubuntu more than a few times, for various reasons, not all of them being my fault. Using GParted and Gpart I managed to restore my files during my last attempt.

[image: screenshot Gparted]

I understand how GParted works, but I'm uncertain about what will happen if I start to delete some or all of the partitions preceding what is hopefully my last Ubuntu download. Should I just leave them alone?

Comment: You've provided no specific Ubuntu product/release details, so speaking generically, you can delete any partition(s) that aren't involved in the booting of your system (be it uEFI or *legacy* as you didn't say). I can't see details of how it boots in what you provided.  My 2c.

Comment: @guiverc The `/dev/sda6` partition has an esp ( EFI System Partition) flag. The EFI System Partition is an OS-independent partition that is mandatory for UEFI boot. I still don't know if he's running 22.04 or whatever version of *buntu he's running because he didn't say.

Comment: @karel You can install all currently supported Ubuntu products without ESP; though its created by default with ISOs using the `ubiquity` installer by default even on *legacy* hardware that doesn't use it (*depends on options installer uses though*).  A default install using `calamares` (ie. Lubuntu, Ubuntu Studio) does not create/use an ESP by default unless required to boot (with uEFI/Secure-uEFI; though warns system may not boot if not created even if not needed), but I don't consider the ESP flag as showing much as I see it on hardware that cannot & thus doesn't use it.

Comment: Provide more information on a) what version of Ubuntu you are using and b) what it exactly is you want to do ( do you want a dual boot with Windows or not ) c) on what partition you want to install Ubuntu and d) if you want a separate partition for your /home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete any partitions that don't have anything in them that you want to keep there. For example if `/dev/sda7`, `/dev/sda8`, `/dev/sda9` and `/dev/sda10` have Ubuntu installations that you aren't using anymore you can delete all of them, but you can't delete the `/dev/sda6` EFI System Partition (esp) which is an OS-independent partition that is required for UEFI boot.

You can browse any partition to check if there are any files that you want to keep there by booting the Ubuntu live USB that you used to install Ubuntu, and running an Ubuntu live session from it.

Comment: "You can delete any partitions that don't have anything in them that you want to keep there". Thanks. So how do I know if I need them? is the basic question I suppose.

Comment: You can browse any partition by booting the Ubuntu live USB that you used to install Ubuntu, and running an Ubuntu live session from it.